# spockframework: check expected result after every feature

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I am using spockframework and geb for test automation. I would like to execute after every feature a simple check to be sure that no error dialogs are shown, I have added the following cleanup() method:

```
 def cleanup() {
    expect:
    $('.myErrrorDialogClass').isEmpty()
 }
```

The code is executed after every feature but it does not throw any error when the dialog is shown.

Comment: I am not sure that `cleanup` is meant to have assertions in it. Are you sure that your expectation is actually executed as assertion? If you really need to do this in `cleanup` maybe try it with a normal `assert` call rather than an expectation.

Comment: I need to do this after every feature/test. From the documentation I have seen that cleanup() is executed after every feature. But perhaps, as you said, is not meant to have assertions in it. Any other alternative?

Comment: You could try just using an `assert` call. Spock uses AST transforms to wire in the proper behavior for its labels (`when`,`expect`, etc) and maybe they don't even run the transformations on the `cleanup` method. A simple `assert` would still work since it's part of Groovy itself.

Comment: You are right! My only concern was that a simple assert in the cleanup method was not part of the test reports. I tried an it works like a charm: when the test fails the report includes it. Wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock uses AST transforms to wire in the functionality for each test label (`when`, `expect`, etc); they may not run the transformations on the `cleanup` method. They are either not expecting or not encouraging assertions in cleanup, so that code may run but not actually assert anything.

You can get around this by using a standard Groovy `assert` call without the `expect` block.

> Summarized from our comment discussion above - in case you want to accept it as an answer ;-)